# remote add origin をタイプミスしたので修正したい

Tags: git

```
git remote add origin URL
```

ここでoriginをタイポして、orignにしてしまったのですが、修正可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git remote` で名前を確認した後、以下のコマンドで変更可能です。

```
$ git remote rename <old> <new>
```

今回の場合なら

```
$ git remote rename orign origin
```

---

なお、コマンドの最後に `-help` を付けると実行方法を確認できます。

```
$ git remote -help
usage: git remote [-v | --verbose]
   or: git remote add [-t <branch>] [-m <master>] [-f] [--tags | --no-tags] [--mirror=<fetch|push>] <name> <url>
   or: git remote rename <old> <new>
   or: git remote remove <name>
   or: git remote set-head <name> (-a | --auto | -d | --delete | <branch>)
   or: git remote [-v | --verbose] show [-n] <name>
   or: git remote prune [-n | --dry-run] <name>
   or: git remote [-v | --verbose] update [-p | --prune] [(<group> | <remote>)...]
   or: git remote set-branches [--add] <name> <branch>...
   or: git remote get-url [--push] [--all] <name>
   or: git remote set-url [--push] <name> <newurl> [<oldurl>]
   or: git remote set-url --add <name> <newurl>
   or: git remote set-url --delete <name> <url>

    -v, --verbose         be verbose; must be placed before a subcommand
```

Comment: 毎回毎回ググるだけでなくて、helpも使っていくと自分のしらないコマンドにも出会えて幅がひろがりそうです。ありがとうございます。